# Need I have a Vnet and Subnet for connect my App Servicce and SQL Server?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I need your help to try to improve the performance of my Web Applications when querying my databases. I attach my scheme, as I have it outlined:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEJPF.png)

And I summarize:

I have two Resource Groups
3 Web Aplicattion
2 SQL Server

And they are organized as follows:

Resource Group 1

- 2 Web Aplicattion
- 1 Database

Resource Group 2

- 1 Web Application
- 1 Database

Everything is within the same Azure region

You can see in the image I have created a Vnet, with two subnets.
And likewise, each SQL Server has a private endpoint created.
App Services are also integrated with the Vnet.

And my query is the following:

1. Is all this necessary for network traffic to be internal, and thereby improve query times?
2. How can I monitor the traffic between the AppServices and the DBs to see where the traffic is going?

I hope your help. Thank you

Comment: What profiling have you done to pinpoint the performance issue? Network latency is unlikely to be a problem unless you're generating huge queries that return a lot of data.

Comment: I do not understand what it refers to with the profile used.

Is there no panel where you can do a 'tracert' to check the network traffic between the web application and the database?

Comment: Daniel referred to [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)), not profiles.

Answer (score 0):

1. No you dont need to add you app and database to network to make it faster, when you use Server name (yourservername.database.windows.net) azure will take care to navigate your calls to databases via fastest route.

But I would recommend you to restrict access to your database:

a. you can use firewall and allow you WebApp outbound IPS (Goto your APP -> Networking (preview) then you will see outbound IPS)

b. You can use Private endpoint but again its not about about performance its about security since then you will be able to restrict who can access your database via more advanced rules.

2. I think the easiest way is to enable [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) then you will see it as dependency and you can see what query was sent, how much time and so on. The second option is more advanced option would be to use private endpoint and networking then you could use [Azure Network Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/network-insights-overview).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.

However, there are two things that I fail to understand.

1. What do you mean by using my db's url? And how do I use it?
2. How do I know which traffic route is being used when I make a query from my app service to the db? Is there any tool to monitor it? And when you mean a network and a private endpoint is not what I already have?

Comment: @Calej updated my answer. Sorry confuse you a bit by url i mean just use servername which azure shows you. 2. I updated application insights is a tool which helps you too see all dependencies you app is calling.